# cancel and start a new async task based on navigation

Tags: wpf, mvvm, async-await, collectionviewsource

I have a WPF form which screen is split in 2 parts as a master detail form. The above part is the master and it shows a bunch of records in a datagrid that is databind to a collectionviewsource.
Whenever the user clicks a row, the bottom part of the form is built up by reacting to the collectionviewsource.current_changed event.
In there I am cancelling any pending async operations, and starting a new one.
The code is like this :

```
if (_tokenSource != null) //_tokenSource is an instance variable of the class that implements current_changed
{
    try
    {
        _tokenSource.Cancel(); //needed because _tokenSource might be disposed already. Ugly.
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
    }
}

using (_tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource())
{
    try
    {
        _unitOfWork = await loadRelatieAsync(relatieId, _tokenSource.Token); // this is just currently an await Task.Delay(5000,token).ConfigureAwait(true); return null;
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
    }
}
//_tokenSource = null; can’t do this, it would lead to several operations not being cancelled
```

What I have here seems to work, but the code is ugly, the application is still a bit sluggish. Is there a proper/better way to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't generally bother disposing the `CancellationTokenSource`. If you just overwrite it without disposing it, the code is cleaner:

```
if (_tokenSource != null)
  _tokenSource.Cancel();

_tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
try
{
  _unitOfWork = await loadRelatieAsync(relatieId, _tokenSource.Token);
  return null;
}
catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
{
}
```

Regarding the "sluggishness", I posit a guess that it could be due to the user quickly changing the selected item in the master view? If so, you may want to introduce a small (say, 100ms) delay *before* starting the new operation. This can be done with `async` code as such:

```
if (_tokenSource != null)
{
  _tokenSource.Cancel();
  _tokenSource = null;
}

var currentItem = _whateverView.CurrentItem;
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
if (currentItem != _whateverView.CurrentItem)
  return null;

_tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
try
{
  _unitOfWork = await loadRelatieAsync(relatieId, _tokenSource.Token);
  return null;
}
catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
{
}
```

Although I must say that if you're doing a lot of "time-based" operations (like "delay this action for a period of time" or "throttle these events based on this time window"), then a more natural approach would be [Reactive Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx).

Comment: spot on, even the waiting for 100ms helps the otherwise sluggish behavior. I'll have to dig through reactive extensions to see how they would fit here.